# Load and web performance test in Visual studio, localhost not starting

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, load-testing

I have one web project and I recently added a new "Web performande and Load test"- project. When I start my recordding I can't go to localhost since it is not started from my web project. What have I missed here? How must I cinfigure my web load test-project??

My goal here is to run the test locally on my machine.

I'm running Windows 7 home premium and VS Ultimate 2013.

Or does it just work if I have my web in one project, start this up in debug mode (F5) and create my load test in another project start that after my web app is up and running??

Comment: What do you mean by "*I can't go to localhost since it is not started from my web project*"? Web Performance tests are recorded within Internet Explorer as it visits the web page, the tests record the HTTP(S) requests and responses between browser and server. When the test runs it repeats the requests and checks the responses.

Comment: What i mean is: i must have one instance of visual studio with My web app and another instance of visual studio that only contains My load test. I thought i could have My load test together with My web app project. When i trie this the load test does not start My web app.

Comment: Visual Studio web tests normally run on one computer and generate HTTP(S) requests that are sent to another computer. Nothing in the web test or the load test is about starting the application on the other computer. For example, web and load tests are used to test a web server and it is expected that the web server is up and running before the test starts. I think you need to do some more reading on the purpose of Visual Studio Web Performance and Load Tests.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do understund now that I need the webserver first up and running and then I can start the load test.